# Filter gridview with pages issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

hello i have grid view that gets 10 records by page.

The problem is if i move to any other page of search result, the filter removes and the grid shows all results.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gridprod.DataSource = d.getprod();
            gridprod.DataBind();
        }


    }

protected void btnsearch1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        gridprod.DataSource = d.Searchprod(lblfield.SelectedValue, txtsearch.Text);
        gridprod.DataBind();
        gridprod.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridprod.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gridprod.DataSource = d.getprod();
        gridprod.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that obvious? Your page index changing method ignores the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have applied a search filter and you page then you should have this:

```
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gridprod.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridprod.DataSource = d.Searchprod(lblfield.SelectedValue, txtsearch.Text);
    gridprod.DataBind()
}
```